# Remove default parameter while setting remote python interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

I tried to set a remote python interpreter in PyCharm. I have set script path, parameters and interpreter options. I have used SFTP with SSH credentials for this configurations.
While I'm running the script, it automatically add a parameter `-u` in between base script and interpreter options. How can I remove this `-u` from the execution command?

this is the command

```
ssh://xxxx@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:22/bin/python -user username -password passphr -u /tmp/pycharm_project_822/backups/back11062018/gen.py
```

Here `-user username -password passphr` I configured as interpreter option and `/tmp/pycharm_project_822/backups/back11062018/gen.py` is the execution file. While I'm running the script, PyCharm automatically add `-u` in between this. I need to remove it.

Comment: you should follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html thin link, will solved your problem

Comment: @AmanJaiswal, I already followed this way. But when I'm running the script, IDE includes another parameter '-u' in between my command..

Comment: Sounds similar to [PY-28339](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28339) ticket in PyCharms' bug tracker. Please feel free to vote/comment there.